# How to attach plugin's function to dynamic created elements in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, selectable

I was attached the `JQuery UI Selectable` to an `UL element`.But the `li item` which inside were **dynamic created**.And of course, I couldn't make selection of them.So, How to attach `plugin's function to dynamic created elements in JQuery`!?

E.g:

```
<ul id="selectable">
    <li class="dataItem">item dynamic created here but you can't select me</li>

</ul>
```

**[update]**

JQuery code:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable();
```

and where I use `delegate` or `live`!?

the way the `delegate` and `live` usage is to bind events in this way:

```
$('#selectable').delegate('li','click',function(){
  // do something here
});
```

but the `selectable plugin's events` are:

```
Supply a callback function to handle the selected event as an init option.

$( ".selectable" ).selectable({
   selected: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

and the newly added item didn't get the `selectable plugin's` state like:

```
ui-selectee

So,should I re-attach the plugin at every time when a new item added!?
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: `So,should I re-attach the plugin at every time when a new item added!?` - I'm afraid that would be yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

---

well, for your **update**, call `$( "#selectable" ).selectable();` right after the time you have attach `#selectable` element in the DOM.

for example,

```
$('#selectable').click(function(){
    alert('I will not fire');
});

$('body').append('<ul id="selectable"><li class="dataItem">item</li></ul>');

$('#selectable').click(function(){
    alert('I will fire');
});
```

`alert('I will fire');` will be the only alert triggered.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery offers [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which will do exactly what you want.

"Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."